# Mounting Server Folder - Accessing files through application server

Tags: java

I have 4 Linux machines where applications runs on 3 and 1 Linux file server where i have stored files.

1. application server1 has port 192.168.1.101:8080
2. application server2 has port 192.168.1.102:8080
3. application server3 has port 192.168.1.103:8080
4. file server has ip 195.168.1.108 - has images directory where images are stored

#4 has folder images and it has been mounted on all the application servers 1, 2, 3 as `/images`

Assume common domain name configured:  [www.imageprocessing.com](http://www.imageprocessing.com) and internally routed with load balancing to hit any of the application servers.

Now will I be able to access the above images as [www.imageprocessing.com/images/1.jpeg](http://www.imageprocessing.com/images/1.jpeg) ? I want to access the images via a direct URL.

Please advise.

Thanks

Accessing Images via Direct URL through mounting of drive and application server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think that's even a good idea? The security implications would be tremendous were this so simply possible.

You're going to need to have some sort of process running on the web servers that retrieves the images from the other machine and serves them to the client. Which means you're also going to need to have security set up to allow that process access to that machine (possibly through sftp or scp, or through a web service with the server for that running on the machine hosting the images).

There possibly is a very crude way, by mapping the remote directory on the image hosting server through a symlink to a directory in the static content directory of the web servers, but that's a major security risk.

Comment: can we create a GET REST API and sends the image content? in that way it will be secured..basically intercept the URL

Comment: TIF or Stream with content-type as image ? Pls help me

Comment: @dolphinkens yes, you can create a REST API through which the web servers can request the image data from the image server. REST server sends the image data back and the web server streams it to where it needs to go. That's how such things are usually handled.